# How to get return type of constructor lambda

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I was wondering if it is possible to get the return type of a Supplier that was assigned to a constructor.

E.g.

```
Supplier<Foo> sFoo = Foo::new;
```

How do I get "Foo.class" from the supplier? I have been using [typetools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) to solve this problem for other things.

This works, for example:

```
Supplier<Foo> sFoo = () -> new Foo();
Class<?> fooClasss = net.jodah.typetools.TypeResolver.resolveRawArguments(Supplier.class, sFoo.getClass())[0];
// fooClass == Foo.class
```

But if I assign Supplier like: `Supplier<Foo> sFoo = Foo::new`, the return type cannot be resolved...

Any thoughts? I don't have to use typetools btw...

Comment: ```sFoo.get().getClass()```

Comment: Yes that would work; however, I would prefer to not invoke the method just to get the return type. It would be nice to get it by some other means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that parsing method references is not supported currently by typeTools. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools/issues/14) with the similar problem.

In general such feature is quite fragile as runtime lambda representation is not specified and implementation dependent. So it may break one day. If you actually need a class I would suggest passing the actual `Class<?>` argument.

Comment: Well, it does handle method references, but not constructor references as it stumbles at the fact that a constructor’s bytecode signature has a `void` return type (thus, constructors need special treatment). However, you’re right that’s such a hack, it’s not worth thinking about it.

Comment: I figured as much, but thought I'd see if anyone had better ideas. I suppose the only thing I can do is avoid using constructor references or pass in the class manually.

Comment: @akagixxer, well another option is to submit a patch to typeTools if you really like to stay with it.

Comment: @akagixxer: note that for any kind of method reference, this hack merely returns the target method’s return type, which is not necessarily matching the `Supplier`’s actual type parameter. For lambda expressions, the synthetic method is usually generated with a matching return type, that’s why it appears to work so smooth. But besides that, it is making so many assumptions about the internal workings of the JRE, that even the smallest change may crash it. It’s even possible that there are already corner cases in the current JREs that can change these details for a particular class.

Comment: @Holger: So it sounds like what you are saying is that the only solid way to do what I want is to pass in the ".class" type everywhere I'm interested in knowing about it. Coming from more of a .NET background I'm still learning about the inner-workings of Java...